# Search for the specific string as per the latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data with log-text as per the system recorded.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TblName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TblName
    END

CREATE TABLE #TblName (
    Key1 varchar(50)
    ,DateStamped date
    ,LogText nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('PF1','2021-09-01','Gabriela.Santa 18:26:25  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 9/1/2021  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NEWPDCN')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('PF1','2022-12-26','NhatCuong.Nguyen 08:21:18  OnHold: True -> False  OnHoldDate: 12/23/2022 ->   OnHoldReasonCode: NoCnf ->   OnHoldComment_c: 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG ->   NhatCuong.Nguyen 15:10:42  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 12/26/2022  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NoCnf  OnHoldComment_c:  -> 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('PF1','2023-01-05','NhatCuong.Nguyen 13:37:42  OnHold: True -> False  OnHoldDate: 12/26/2022 ->   OnHoldReasonCode: NoCnf ->   OnHoldComment_c: 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG ->   Quoc.Phan 14:36:24  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 1/5/2023  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NoCnf  OnHoldComment_c:  -> 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG  Nguyen.Anh 14:55:42  OnHold: True -> False  OnHoldDate: 1/5/2023 ->   OnHoldReasonCode: NoCnf ->   OnHoldComment_c: 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG ->   Quoc.Phan 14:57:29  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 1/5/2023  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NoCnf  OnHoldComment_c:  -> 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('PF1','2022-12-23','ThiThanh.Nguyen 10:12:22  AnalysisCode:  -> MachSO  Quoc.Phan 16:11:22  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 12/23/2022  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NoCnf  OnHoldComment_c:  -> 3D for Chemical miliing change, need to update CM BDWG')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('PF1','2021-09-16','Valentin.Opris 12:08:52  OnHold: True -> False  OnHoldDate: 9/1/2021 ->   OnHoldReasonCode: NEWPDCN ->   Bogdan.Stefanescu 17:19:26  OnHold: False -> True  OnHoldDate:  -> 9/16/2021  OnHoldReasonCode:  -> NEWPDCN  Jothimani.Alagappan 17:29:53  ChangeRequestReason_c: CM_V0107 Spirit Sunshine - Move ST in house -> CM_V0330 SPIRIT SUNSHINE - Update Manufacturing Drawing PDCN review')

select * from #TblName
```

I am trying to search the latest user name from **LogText** column who have done the latest transaction in the system and the **LogText** contain **OnHold: False -> True**

So, the output from **#TblName** should be

| Key1 | DateStamped | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PF1 | 2023-01-05 | Quoc.Phan |

Comment: Please tag only the DBMS you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the latest user name in the LogText column that has done a transaction in the system you can use the following query:

```
select t1.key1, t1.datestamped, substring(t1.logtext, charindex('onhold: false -> true', t1.logtext) - 20, 20) as username
from #tblname t1
inner join (
  select key1, max(datestamped) as max_date
  from #tblname
  where logtext like '%onhold: false -> true%'
  group by key1
) t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.datestamped = t2.max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very bad design and you are going to have performance issues in the future. If the `long text` comes from log file or application you need to rewrite in order each event to be spillable correctly. For example, you can use:

- CHAR(29), CHAR(30), CHAR(31) - group, record and unit separator
- XML
- JSON

Then, when the data comes in your table you can use trigger or other routine to split the data and populate it in a normalized manner. For example, you need table for users, for keys,for on hold codes and for events. In the events table you will have:

- key id
- user id
- is on hold
- on hold date
- on hold reason code id

and you will be able to solve task like the ask one easier.